# Cannot find data type HIERARCHYID in Sql Server 2012

Tags: sql, tree, sql-server-2012, hierarchical-data

I have win7, sql server 2012 express, .net Framework 3.5 4.0 4.5. I would like to start tutorial about HierarchyId Data Type but when I try to execute this query, this message arrive :

```
Column, parameter, or variable #1: Cannot find data type HIERARCHYID.
```

And this is the query

```
CREATE TABLE EmployeeOrg
(
   OrgNode HIERARCHYID PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
   OrgLevel AS OrgNode.GetLevel(),
   EmployeeID int UNIQUE NOT NULL,
   EmpName varchar(20) NOT NULL,
   Title varchar(20) NULL
)
```

I'm a newbie in sql server, and i have no idea why this data type cannot be found.
Thanks for any answers.

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting to a SQL-Server 2012 instance? Your SQL is fine, it is working on [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b037f/1). Try running 'SELECT @@VERSION' to check you are connecting to a 2012 instance.

Comment: Result is Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.3042.00 (Intel X86)

Comment: Then that is your answer, although you may be using the 2012 version of management studio, you are connecting to a 2005 instance of SQL Server, so you can only use features supported by SQL Server 2005.